# How to align n number of fixed width elements (divs) inside a parent that stretches 100%

Tags: html, css

This question must have asked in various forms in many ways but I've been searching quite a bit and could not find the answer hence my asking.

I have a div width fixed height, stretching 100% width.

Inside I have 2 divs with same height as the parent, with various widths which in total is less than the parent's width.

I need these divs centered inside the parent, next to each other. I can get one of the divs centered using `text-align: center;` and `margin: 0px auto;` however the other one breaks line. If I get them to `float: left;` or `right`, then they do not get centrally aligned.

What I need (2 elements inside the parents):

```
###############################################################
#                |  El. ||         El.       |                #
#                |  A   ||         B         |                #
#                |      ||                   |                #
###############################################################
```

And if there were 3 elements inside the parent:

```
###############################################################
#       |  El. ||         El.       ||       El.      |       #
#       |  A   ||         B         ||       C        |       #
#       |      ||                   ||                |       #
###############################################################
```

Thank you for your kind help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding an additional div to contain the two inner divs? Then you should be able to center align it with auto margin and set the text-align: center; as well. If the divs still stack, try display:inline.

Comment: Thank you Jim. I checked a few websites (big ones too) and I think the way you suggested, as also used by them, is the correct way to go.

Comment: Glad to help! Hope you get everything working. If not reply back and Ill see if I cant work up an example.

Answer (score 0):

Try displaying the divs in question as

```
display: inline;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put everything into a span element in a centered div:

```
<div align="center" id="container">
    <span id="stuff">content</span>
    <span id="more">more content</span>
</div>
```